# load a different stylesheet in a category post

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

My post template won't load the stylesheet, what's going wrong?

```
function wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles() {
    if ( is_post_template( 'category-bedrijven.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'post-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-interieur.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles' );
```

Comment: you mean is_page_template or ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like-

```
function wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles() {
    if ( is_category('bedrijven') ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'post-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-interieur.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles' );
```

Here ***bedrijven*** is your category slug.

As you said the above method hasn't worked for you, so here I'm suggesting another method-

First remove the first method's full code. Then follow this below method step by step-

**Step 1:** 
In your theme's `functions.php` put the below code block-

```
function the_dramatist_register_category_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'post-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-interieur.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_dramatist_register_category_styles' );
```

By this above code block we are registering your stylesheet file at ***WordPress***. So we can call it anytime.

**Step 2:**
Now go to your `category-bedrijven.php` file and inside this file put the below code-

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style('post-template'); ?>
```

It'll must work if you do it right.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanx for your solution, but it didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: I tested it previously and I just tested it again. I worked both the times. Please inspect your page source and search for if `layout-interieur.css` file is called or not. @bets

Comment: maybe its a taxonomy?

Comment: Nope. He already declared it in his question `category-bedrijven.php`. So how could it be another taxonomy ? @MohamedRihan

Comment: I think @dramatist that you are right the layout-interieur.css isn't in mij page source i dont't know why, because he stands in the root directory and i don't know why he isn't loaded.

Comment: Have you visited *** bedrijven*** this category ? Cause this file will only be loaded in *** bedrijven*** category template. @bets

Comment: Yes i did :) but there is no layout-interieur.css

Comment: sorry i want to put this with me comment <meta property="article:section" content="bedrijven" />

Comment: I've not understood your last comment. Can you please clear your thought  ? @bets

Comment: This is what i get now

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles() (previously declared in /var/www/vhos

Comment: You've declared more than once this same function. Find the previous one and remove it. And wait.. I'm working on a second method. Be patient. @bets

Comment: Check my updated answer. @bets

Comment: We're almost there, thanks to you!! It works like a charme on the category-bedrijven page Only the CSS stylesheet /layout-interieur.css won't work at a post page where i check checkbox with the category-bedrijven

Do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles() {

    if ( is_page_template( 'category-bedrijven.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'cat-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-interieur.css' ); 
    } 
}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_post_template_styles' );
```

Comment: Thanx for your solution but than it is an page and not a category post or am i wrong?

Comment: if you php file name is category-bedrijven.php this my solution will work. category post mean single post or archive page? or custom post type?

Comment: sorry it's a category post

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

$handle = 'wpdocs';

wp_register_style( $handle,

get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/relative/path/to/stylesheet.css', array(), '', true );

if ( is_page_template( 'template-name.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( $handle );
}